# Who can start a Shaka?

Tags: calendar

Recently I heard that a Shaka can be started only by a Chakravarti Samrat. E.g. Shalivan Shaka, Shiva shaka, Yudhishthir Shaka, etc. Also it was said that such Samrat who wants to start a shaka must not have a debt of even a penny. So how a person must be to start a shaka?